# Generate unique URL key for prefilled forms

Tags: jquery, forms, coldfusion

I'm trying to generate a unique url for my form that will contain prepopulated information that we're pulling from a database. The user should receive an email with a link to a form that already contains their Name and Email, and all I would want them to do is enter a password into the form, hit submit and be done.

```
<form id="RegistrationForm">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <label for="RegEmail">Email</label>
        <input id="RegEmail" type="email" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <label for="RegName"> Name</label>
        <input id="RegName" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <label for="RegPassword">Password</label>
        <input id="RegPassword" type="password" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <label for="RegPassConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="RegPassConfirm" type="password" class="form-control" data-match="#RegPassword" data-match-error="Passwords do not match" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
        &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;" id="RegBtn">Register</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Lets say the url for this form is www.mysite.com/test, is there anyway to send the user a url like www.mysite.com/test/jFF89asertFS29 which then links them to said form with the email JohnDoe@yahoo.com and John Doe prefilled out in the email and name fields? Also, I'm not using any PHP in the form, only jquery and coldfusion in the back

Comment: Send the primary key value of the user table in your database.  If that's not sufficiently secure, add a uuid column to the table and use them both.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is the problem with your URL rewrite?

Comment: Well after writing the question, I went on looking through how I might do what I wanted to do... So I guess something I noticed was jquery serialize? 

I guess the question now is how do I take the serialized information that looks like 
"single=Single2&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple2&check=check1&check=check2&radio=radio1" and convert it into some unique url so that when you click the link, it prefills certain parts of the form

Comment: i need to start looking into doing something like this soon. i think something along the lines of what @DanBracuk said is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment above, you would send that information along on the URL, then program the form to use it using the URL scope. This is pretty basic programming.

For example, your link would be

```
blah.cfm?Regname=bob&regemail=bob@example.com
```

At the top of the form page (blah.cfm in my example link) you would have

Then inside your form you would have the following:

```
<input id="RegEmail" type="email" class="form-control" 
          value="<cfoutput>#url.regname#</cfoutput>" required>

<input id="Regname" type="Regname" class="form-control" 
          value="<cfoutput>#url.Regname#</cfoutput>" required>
```

NOTE: you probably need to urlencode those vars as well.

This would "pre-populate" your form with whatever URL vars you pass along. Of course you can pass them in the FORM scope as well.